# Eliminar contenido de elemento DIV de HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5

Cual es la forma correcta de eliminar el contenido de un elemento `<div id="root"></div>` de HTML 5 si este elemento contiene a otros elementos `<div></div>`, he probado estas dos opciones y funcionan ambas, pero me gustaría saber cual es la correcta o la diferencia entre usar una u otro.

Primera forma:

```
var div = document.getElementById('root');
while (div.firstChild) {
    div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
}
```

Segunda forma:

```
document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = '';
```

Comment: en teoría la función que hace lo que quieres específicamente que es borrar los nodos es la primera forma, ya en caso que tengas demasiados hijos dentro del div se te demorara un poco mas ejecutando el ciclo, mas con el innerHTML eliminas todo directamente de manera genérica e inmediata. Ya es basado en tu gusto.

Answer (score 3):

En teoría la función que hace lo que quieres específicamente que es borrar los nodos es la primera forma:

```
var div = document.getElementById('root');
while (div.firstChild) {
    div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
}
```

ya en caso que tengas demasiados hijos dentro del div se te demorara un poco mas ejecutando el ciclo, pero con el `innerHTML` eliminas todo directamente de manera genérica e inmediata. Ya es basado en tu gusto.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui te dejo una opcion y eliminas en este caso todos los nodos hijos saludos espero te ayude

```js
function aliminarHijos() {
  var padre = document.getElementById("padre");
  for (var i = 0; i < padre.children.length; i++) {
    var hijo = padre.children[i]
    padre.remove(hijo)
  }
}
```

```css
#padre {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: auto;
  background: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}
#padre > div {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0,.1);
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="aliminarHijos()" type="button" name="button">Eliminar Hijos</button>

<div id="padre">
  <div class="hijo1">
    hijo 1
  </div>
  <div class="hijo2">
    hijo 2
  </div>
   <div class="hijo1">
    hijo 3
  </div>
  <div class="hijo2">
    hijo 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Realmente la lógica viene siendo prácticamente la misma, solo cambiaste el ciclo `while` por un ciclo `for`, saludos ! :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const e = document.getElementById("main"),
      deleted = [];
Array.from(e.childNodes).forEach( child => {e.removeChild(child); deleted.push(child.tagName);});


console.log(deleted); // Ver eliminados
```

```html
<div id="main"><h1>Hola</h1><br><i>wow</i><p> !! </p><hr></div>
```